# How do I disable the popup box that says "Are you sure?" when I delete a row from my DB in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm diving into Ruby on Rails and I find that when I'm using the scaffold code that RoR generated for my model, it causes a confirmation box to appear that reads "Are you sure?" when I click on the delete link.  What causes this to appear and how do I remove it?  Thanks, I'm just trying to figure out how this all works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scaffold link_to will look something like this:

`<%= link_to "Destroy", @code, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>`

Removing the `:confirm => 'Are you sure?',` argument to the link helper will remove the javascript confirmation alert.

Answer (score 0):

The link in the template has a :confirm=>"My message here" option. If you remove that option, then it won't have a message.